# Interactively edit UV mapped, textured mesh in Cinema 4D without distorting texture?

Tags: textures, uv-mapping, cinema-4d

I'm fairly new to Cinema and I'm building a rigged flat (2d) character out of illustrated pieces. I want the meshes to have an efficient number of polys but sufficient resolution where they'll bend most, so I'm starting with planes and mostly knifing away. Part of this process is roughly following the contour of the piece (say, an arm) with the edge of the mesh. I'm fine with the modeling, but I think I may be doing the texturing in a somewhat roundabout way, and I'm wondering if you can suggest a better technique.

My pipeline requires that all the textures be UVW mapped with no offset or scale. (I'm exporting to Unity through FBX)

Basically it's like this:

- Set the texture tag to Flat projection
- Modify the mesh (moving vertices, adding and removing vertices, etc)
- Go back to UVW projection
- In BodyPaint's UV Manager, in UV Poly Edit Mode, choose Flat projection fitted to object system.

The only problem with this is that if I have to tweak the mesh later, I'll have to go back into Flat projection so that moving the mesh vertices doesn't stretch the texture... and for some reason, after I've made a bunch of edits, the frontal mapping ends up requiring scale and offset to align again. Of course, I have to zero these out again when I'm satisfied and go back to UVW mapping. It really seems like an awful workaround to what should be a simple task.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I interactively move the vertices around while keeping a flat UV mapping, without switching back and forth in the Texture tag?